# Django - invalid literal for int() with base 10: Value is a string not a integer

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I am receiving the following error and not sure why. invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'UNI-KIT'. When I call the value via the template. I just can not wrap my head around why I am getting an integer error when it is a string and model is a CharField.

```
Models.py
    from django.db import models
    from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
    from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True)
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.category_name)
        super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    #def get_absolute_url(self):
        #return reverse('products:category', args=[self.id]) #kwargs={'slug': self.slug}

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_name

class Company(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    company_url = models.URLField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=500)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.company_name)
        super(Company, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    #def get_absolute_url(self):
        #return reverse('products:category', args=[self.id]) #kwargs={'slug': self.slug}

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company_name

class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    manufacturer_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=500)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.manufacturer_name)
        super(Manufacturer, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    #def get_absolute_url(self):
        #return reverse('products:category', args=[self.id]) #kwargs={'slug': self.slug}

    def __str__(self):
        return self.manufacturer_name

class Product(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    product_description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, blank=True, null=True)
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer, blank=True, null=True)
    buy_link = models.URLField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    product_image_url = models.URLField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    orginal_price = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    stock = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=500)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.product_name)
        super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('products:product_detail', args=[self.slug]) #kwargs={'slug': self.slug}

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name
```

Views

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger

import os, csv, sys
from django.db.models import Q

from .models import Category, Company, Product, Manufacturer

# Create your views here.
def upload(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect("home")

    csv_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    try:
        with open(csv_path + '/product.csv') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for row in reader:
                _, created = Product.objects.get_or_create(
                    product_name=row[0],
                    buy_link=row[2],
                    product_image_url=row[3],
                    price=row[4],
                    orginal_price=row[5],
                    product_description=row[6],
                    stock=row[7],
                    sku=row[10],
                )
                _, created = Company.objects.get_or_create(
                    company_name=row[1],
                )

                _, created = Manufacturer.objects.get_or_create(
                    manufacturer_name=row[8],
                )

                _, created = Category.objects.get_or_create(
                    category_name=row[9],
                )
        success = "Added to database"
        context = {"success": success}

    except csv.Error as e:
        print(e)
        context = {'error': e}

    template = "products/add.html"

    return render(request, template, context)

def products_all(request):
    products = Product.objects.order_by("-date_added")

    paginator = Paginator(products, 12)
    page = request.GET.get('page')

    try:
        product = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        product = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        product = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    template = "products/all.html"
    context = {'product': product, 'products': products}

    return render(request, template, context)

def product_detail(request, slug):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=slug)

    template = "products/detail.html"
    context = {'product': product}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

template

```
{% block content %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <img src="{{ product.product_image_url }}">
        </div>
        <div class="col-8">
            <h2>{{ product.product_name }}</h2>
            <hr>
            <h3>Product Description:</h3>
            <p>{{ product.product_description }}</p>
            <p>Manufacturer: {{ product.manufacturer.manufacturer_name }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

urls

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'backend/upload$', views.upload, name="upload"),
    url(r'^product/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.product_detail, name="product_detail"),
    url(r'$', views.products_all, name="products_all"),
]
```

Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/compare/product/avery-5167-labels-compatibles-also-for-5267-5667-8167-50-sheets-4000-labels/

Django Version: 1.10.6
Python Version: 3.6.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
 'products']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:

In template /Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/compare/compare/templates/products/detail.html, error at line 14
   invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'UNI-KIT'   4 : {% block content %}
   5 :     <div class="row">
   6 :         <div class="col-4">
   7 :             <img src="{{ product.product_image_url }}">
   8 :         </div>
   9 :         <div class="col-8">
   10 :             <h2>{{ product.product_name }}</h2>
   11 :             <hr>
   12 :             <h3>Product Description:</h3>
   13 :             <p>{{ product.product_description }}</p>
   14 :             <p>Manufacturer:  {{ product.manufacturer.manufacturer_name }} </p>
   15 :         </div>
   16 :     </div>
   17 : {% endblock %}

Traceback:

File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/compare/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _resolve_lookup
  885.                     current = current[bit]

During handling of the above exception ('Product' object is not subscriptable), another exception occurred:

File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/compare/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py" in __get__
  170.             rel_obj = getattr(instance, self.cache_name)

During handling of the above exception ('Product' object has no attribute '_manufacturer_cache'), another exception occurred:

File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/compare/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  42.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/compare/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/compare/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/compare/compare/products/views.py" in product_detail
  74.     return render(request, template, context)

File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/compare/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  30.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/compare/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  68.     return template.render(context, request)

File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/compare/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  66.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/compare/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  208.                     return self._render(context)

File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/compare/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/compare/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/compare/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/compare/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  174.         return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/compare/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/compare/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/compare/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/compare/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  70.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/compare/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/compare/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/compare/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  1044.             output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)

File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/compare/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in resolve
  711.                 obj = self.var.resolve(context)

File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/compare/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in resolve
  852.             value = self._resolve_lookup(context)

File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/compare/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _resolve_lookup
  893.                         current = getattr(current, bit)

File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/compare/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py" in __get__
  177.                 qs = qs.filter(self.field.get_reverse_related_filter(instance))

File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/compare/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in filter
  796.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/compare/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  814.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))

File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/compare/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in add_q
  1227.         clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)

File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/compare/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in _add_q
  1247.                     current_negated, allow_joins, split_subq)

File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/compare/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in _add_q
  1253.                     allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,

File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/compare/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in build_filter
  1187.             condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)

File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/compare/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in build_lookup
  1083.                 return final_lookup(lhs, rhs)

File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/compare/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py" in __init__
  19.         self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()

File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/compare/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py" in get_prep_lookup
  59.             return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)

File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/compare/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_prep_value
  946.         return int(value)

Exception Type: ValueError at /compare/product/avery-5167-labels-compatibles-also-for-5267-5667-8167-50-sheets-4000-labels/
Exception Value: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'UNI-KIT'
```

Comment: Is this the full code? Which view is handling `/compare/product/` URL?

Comment: added urls.py file above the traceback

Comment: product_detail view is handling the /compare/product/ url

Comment: Does this happens to

Comment: There are multiple exceptions being raised here - `'Product' object is not subscriptable` and `'Product' object has no attribute '_manufacturer_cache'` and finally the `ValueError`. I'm not quite sure what's causing these.

Comment: With help from @nik_m we figured out my csv import was not importing strings so it was returning ints.